# capitalize first letter in Report Builder filed

Tags: sql-server, reporting, reportbuilder3.0

I am writing a report using report builder and the one of the filed value of the data set is in upper-case I want to capitalize first letter of this data field value in the text box. Please let me know if you could help.

Thanks
Yogi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using a query from the database to fetch your data through a connection object. Based on what you've said here, a reasonable approach would be:

```
SELECT UPPER(LEFT([FIELD],1))+LOWER(SUBSTRING([FIELD],2,LEN([FIELD])))
```

If you have more than one word in your data, you will have to create a UDF to handle to pascal casing:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[pCase] 
( 
    @strIn VARCHAR(255) 
) 
RETURNS VARCHAR(255) 
AS 
BEGIN 
    IF @strIn IS NULL 
        RETURN NULL 

    DECLARE 
        @strOut VARCHAR(255), 
        @i INT, 
        @Up BIT, 
        @c VARCHAR(2) 

    SELECT 
        @strOut = '', 
        @i = 0,  
        @Up = 1 

    WHILE @i <= DATALENGTH(@strIn) 
    BEGIN 
        SET @c = SUBSTRING(@strIn,@i,1) 
        IF @c IN (' ','-','''') 
        BEGIN 
            SET @strOut = @strOut + @c 
            SET @Up = 1 
        END 
        ELSE 
        BEGIN 
            IF @up = 1 
                SET @c = UPPER(@c) 
            ELSE 
                SET @c = LOWER(@c) 

            SET @strOut = @strOut + @c 
            SET @Up = 0 
        END 
        SET @i = @i + 1 
    END 
    RETURN @strOut 
END
```

And then utilise the function like so:

```
SELECT DBO.PCASE([FIELD])
```

Comment: Thanks Jonny yes you are right, the problem is this value do have space in it so the second words's first character should be capitalized as well. like for example Johnny Bell.

Comment: I've edited my answer to reflect your needs. Hope it does the job.

Comment: If it works, upvote and mark as answer to help others in the future, and give me rep :)

Answer (score 5):

In the report, you can do the casing with the Common Text Fuction StrConv() to make proper casing (first character of every word in capitals):

`StrConv([Field].value, vbProperCase)`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/strconv-function

If you only want the first character capitalized (and leave the rest as is):

`UCase(Left([Field].value, 1)) & Right([Field].value, Len([Field].value) - 1)`

(the question title refers to Report Builder, so the given answer in SQL might not suit erveryones needs)